# connecting python script to kafka docker container

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka

I may overthinking this and I most likely am, cause I've gotten this to work before but not sure how. I have a docker container that boots up kafka and I'm trying to produce some records but getting a `kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable` in my code so I'm not sure I'm calling it right. So here is a portion of my docker compose that creates the kafka instance.

```
  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    image: debezium/kafka:latest
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:9092:9092"
    links:
      - zookeeper
    environment: 
      - ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
    volumes: 
        - ./kafka/data:/kafka/data
        - ./kafka/logs:/kafka/logs
```

And here is my python code I'm trying to run. (I also have zookeeper in my docker image above, but feeling like this piece is the piece that is relevant).

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer, KafkaProducer
import json
from json import loads
from csv import DictReader 


bootstrap_servers = ['kafka:9092']
topicname='test-topic'
producer=KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers)
producer=KafkaProducer()

with open('test_data_producer.csv', 'r') as new_obj:
   csv_dict_reader=DictReader(new_obj)
   for row in csv_dict_reader:
       ack = producer.send(topicname, json.dumps(row).encode('utf-8'))
       metadata = ack.get()
       print(metadata.topic, metadata.partition)
```

Comment: 1) Show a [mcve] of your full compose file 2) You need to add Python app to the same compose file to resolve `kafka` service name. 3) Debezium image doesn't expose `ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=kafka` by default, I don't think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

producer is not able to connect broker since `kafka` is not valid dns name, if you add following in your hosts file `127.0.0.1 kafka` and `127.0.0.1 zookeeper` then your producer should be able to connect kafka.